# Select Case number range not registering

Tags: vba, excel, switch-statement

I have a simple case statement below that should be evaluating -1 in the `Case -1 To -10` case and it is skipping over it.  I initially thought the bug was stemming from `Select Case Val(firstOptionLegArray(UBound(firstOptionLegArray))) + Val(secondOptionLegArray(UBound(secondOptionLegArray)))` in that it wasn't evaluating to what I expected (In this specific case it should be +1 + -2).

Ran a `Debug.Print` line and it is in fact evaluating to -1 as expected.  What am I missing?

```
Debug.Print Val(firstOptionLegArray(UBound(firstOptionLegArray))) + Val(secondOptionLegArray(UBound(secondOptionLegArray)))

                Select Case Val(firstOptionLegArray(UBound(firstOptionLegArray))) + Val(secondOptionLegArray(UBound(secondOptionLegArray)))

                    Case 0
                    'No ratio

                        assemblyString = "LIVE " & GetOptionCodes(Mid(tradeLegStructureArray(0), 8, 2)) & " " & TranslateExpirationDate(firstOptionLegArray(3)) & " " & Format(firstOptionLegArray(5), "##0.00") & "/" & _
                        Format(secondOptionLegArray(5), "##0.00") & " Fence"

                    Case -1 To -10
                    'Ratio

                        assemblyString = "LIVE " & GetOptionCodes(Mid(tradeLegStructureArray(0), 8, 2)) & " " & TranslateExpirationDate(firstOptionLegArray(3)) & " " & Format(firstOptionLegArray(5), "##0.00") & "/" & _
                        Format(secondOptionLegArray(5), "##0.00") & " " & Abs(firstOptionLegArray(UBound(firstOptionLegArray))) & "x" & Abs(secondOptionLegArray(UBound(secondOptionLegArray))) & " Fence"

                End Select
```

Comment: You have to write the lower number first. So: `Case -10 To -1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values need to be in ascending order in the Case `line`:

```
Case -10 To -1
```